# Replace Normal.dotm via GPO not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, microsoft-office-2013

I don't even want to ask as it seems such a simple problem, but I fear I have to as none of the google suggestions worked for me.

I am trying to replace the "Normal.dotm" file which is located in %appdata%\Microsoft\Templates with a "File Replace GPO".

The policy itself is being applied, but not replacing the file. Also I don't see any errors in the event log. Permissions on the share from where I copy the files from are fine too (netlogon share). Tried to access it with my test user with no problems.

Below you see the policy which I created for the replacement. Does someone have an idea why this is not working? I don't get it.

File Replace GPO:

[image]

DC is Server 2008R2 and Client is Win7 with Office 2013

The source path is not completely visible on the screenshot. It is:

```
%LOGONSERVER%\netlogon\StandardFont\*
```

Comment: Why * rather than * . *  as an all-inclusive wildcard for files in that folder?

Comment: I tried that in the beginning but didn't work either. On google I've read that you need to use it with just one * I also tried using absolute paths. Didn't work either.

Comment: Question can be closed. I have solved it with KIX now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you need to put normal.dotm in your destination path.
`%appdata%\microsoft\Template\normal.dotm`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).